# Spark Streaming commitASync: OffsetOutOfRangeException

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, streaming, spark-streaming, offset

I've designed a Spark Streaming application which runs on 120-second micro batches essentially transforming JSON to Avro files.

Since I started consuming a new Kafka topic, I'm running into an issue where I randomly get OffsetOutOfRangeException on every few micro-batches.

These micro batches are very small, around 20 messages, and only take a few seconds to complete.

At the end of my program, I commitASync and can confirm, using OffsetCallBack, that these commits are successful to Kafka.

The only way I've been able to eliminate this error is mirroring the messages into another Kafka topic (with the same properties as the first).

Using the main topic, I've tried solving the problem on my application level by Increasing Spark resources (executor memory, driver memory, YARN queue), Disabling Kafka consumer cache, Upgrading Spark to 2.4.0, Reducing micro batch time to 30s, 60s, Increasing my fault tolerance setting to allow more errors

```
b'2019-04-24 12:24:01,218 INFO  - Computing topic xx.xx.xx.xx.xx, partition 0 offsets 1190252 -> 1190271\n'
b'2019-04-24 12:26:00,003 INFO  - xx.xx.xx.xx.EntryPoint$$anonfun$main$13$$anon$1: Offset onComplete for - xx.xx.xx.xx.xx- 0 - 1190252\n'
b'2019-04-24 12:26:00,003 INFO  - xx.xx.xx.xx.EntryPoint$$anonfun$main$13$$anon$1: Offsets successfully committed\n'
b'2019-04-24 12:26:00,092 INFO  - Computing topic xx.xx.xx.xx.xx, partition 0 offsets 1190271 -> 1190295\n'
b'2019-04-24 12:26:00,114 WARN  - Lost task 0.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 27, xx, executor 1): org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetOutOfRangeException: Offsets out of range with no configured reset policy for partitions: {xx.xx.xx.xx.xx-0=1190272}\n\tat org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseFetchedData(Fetcher.java:589)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:355)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1000)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:938)\n\tat org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.poll(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:136)\n\tat org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.get(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:71)\n\tat org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:271)\n\tat org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:2...
b'2019-04-24 12:26:00,114 WARN  - Lost task 0.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 27, xx, executor 1): org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetOutOfRangeException: Offsets out of range with no configured reset policy for partitions: {xx.xx.xx.xx.xx-0=1190272}\n\tat org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseFetchedData(Fetcher.java:589)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:355)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1000)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:938)\n\tat org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.poll(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:136)\n\tat org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.get(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:71)\n\tat org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:271)\n\tat org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:2...
b'2019-04-24 12:26:00,119 INFO  - Computing topic xx.xx.xx.xx.xx, partition 0 offsets 1190271 -> 1190295\n'
b'2019-04-24 12:26:00,247 WARN  - Lost task 0.1 in stage 8.0 (TID 28, xx, executor 1): org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetOutOfRangeException: Offsets out of range with no configured reset policy for partitions: {xx.xx.xx.xx.xx-0=1190271}\n\tat org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseFetchedData(Fetcher.java:589)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:355)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1000)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:938)\n\tat org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.poll(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:136)\n\tat org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.get(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:68)\n\tat org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:271)\n\tat org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:2...
b'2019-04-24 12:26:00,247 WARN  - Lost task 0.1 in stage 8.0 (TID 28, xx, executor 1): org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetOutOfRangeException: Offsets out of range with no configured reset policy for partitions: {xx.xx.xx.xx.xx-0=1190271}\n\tat org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseFetchedData(Fetcher.java:589)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:355)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1000)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:938)\n\tat org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.poll(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:136)\n\tat org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.get(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:68)\n\tat org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:271)\n\tat org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:2...
b'2019-04-24 12:26:00,252 INFO  - Computing topic xx.xx.xx.xx.xx, partition 0 offsets 1190271 -> 1190295\n'
```

I've all but ruled out there anything I can do on the application level, why can't I read these offsets from Kafka when I clearly just committed them on my previous run?